# If $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-} f(x)=\infty$ Then $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}f'(x)=\infty $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

Here's my question:

> Let $f$ be a continuous function in $[a,b)$ (semi closed interval) which is differentiable twice in $(a,b)$, such that $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.
>
> Prove that  $$\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to b^-}f'(x)=\infty$$

In the question I have a hint:

> With the mean value theorem prove that if $f'$ is bounded then $f$ is bounded.

Actually I didn't have much success with the hint. Instead, my claim is that if $f'$ is bounded, then $f$ is uniformly continuous (I can prove that), and then its limit is finite, which is a contradiction to the assumption of infinite limit. I don't know if I'm right.

How can I use the hint? can I use my solution?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Is $b<\infty?\ $

Comment: It must be, otherwise the assertion doesn't follow.

Comment: @zhw. Yes, it is.

Comment: MVT will show that $f'$ cannot be bounded. Then use the fact that since the second derivative is positive, $f'$ must be increasing.

Comment: Actually, if $ not \space q \implies not \space p$ then $p \implies q$ .. So, if you can prove that $f$ is bounded whenever $f'$ is bounded, you are actually proving that $f'$ is unbounded whenever $f$ is unbounded which is what is required to be proven.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I can't find the contradiction with MVT. I keep getting: $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\le M \rightarrow f(b)-f(a)\le M*(b-a)$. But... what now?

Comment: @Deepak Gupta -- Not exactly. It is required to show that the derivative tends to infinity, which is a stronger statement than being just undbounded.

Comment: @Alan -- Mathematics takes time. You don't go solving problems in 30 seconds.

Comment: @uniquesolution If I proved that it's unbounded, I can conclude that it tends to $\infty$ since it's increasing.

Comment: @AndréNicolas -- so in fact is would suffice to assume that $f^{''}>0$  in $(b-\delta,b)$ for some $\delta>0$...

Comment: @Alan, yes, that's clear. Now prove it's not bounded.

Comment: @uniquesolution can I use the fact that $|b-a| \le \delta$ and then say $f(b)-f(a) < M* \delta$?

Comment: Forget the $\delta$. It is not connected to your problem. It is a comment directed to someone else.

Comment: Suppose that there is an interval $(c,b)$ in which the derivative is bounded above by $M$. Then for any $t$ in this interval we have $f(t)\le f(c)+(t-c)M$, which is less than $f(c)+(b-c)M$.

Comment: @uniquesolution: Sorry, I did not see your comment until now. Yes, $f''$ positive near $b$ is good enough.  All we want to avoid is $f$ grows fast then slowly, then fast, and so on. If we remove all conditions on $f''$, it is not hard to construct counterexamples.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so you're saying that$ f(c)+(b-c)*M$ is the biggest value I'll get since the interval is $[a,b)$, and $(b-c) $is the biggest value I'll get? Did I get it right?

Comment: Roughly right. It is not the biggest value you will get, since you will in fact never get it. But definitely if the derivative is $\le M$ you will never get a bigger value, which is enough to contradict the fact that $f(x)$ blows up as $x$ approaches $b$ from the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the contrapositive approach, we assume that $f'(x)$ is bounded for all $a<x<b$ for some $a$.  Let's call this bound $B$.  Then, from the MVT, there exists $a<\xi<x$ such that

$$f(x)=f(a) +f'(\xi)(x-a)$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
|f(x)|&\le |f(a)| +|f'(\xi)||(x-a)|\\\\
&\le |f(a)|+B|x-a|
\end{align}$$

for $a<x<b$.  But this implies that $f$ is bounded for $x\in (a,b)$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore, $f'$ is unbounded.

Now, inasmuch as $f''>0$ is given, we have that $f'$ is increasing.  Therefore, as $f'$ is increasing and unbounded we must have $$\lim_{x\to b^{-}}f'(x)=\infty$$

---

Comment: You're welcome.  It was my pleasure.